# Passing shared_ptr to shared object/dll

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I pass a `std::shared_ptr` from a method `func` to a so/dll function `dll_func`, which in turn pushes it into a private dll vector.

Then `dll_func` returns, and `func` returns as well, so that the `std::shared_ptr` in the dll vector is the only `std::shared_ptr` instance.

If later on the dll clears the vector, the `std::shared_ptr` in there is deallocated by the dll or by the calling program that initially created the `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Was the DLL built with the exact same standard library implementation as the calling executable? If not, don't do this. You aren't assured binary compatibility here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::shared_ptr` will be deleted by whatever function was used as the deleter at the time of its creation. If that function is in the dll, then that will be used; if the function was in the exe, then that one. Assuming you use the default `delete`, then is is cleared by the standard library runtime `::operator delete` but it will be called from the code in the dll (assuming the global is not overridden).

*More importantly, when sharing object across the dll boundary, do you use the same compiler and compiler options?* If so, then it should all work as expected. If not, don't share objects this way, there is no guarantee around the binary compatibility.

For clarity;

> If the `std::shared_ptr` was created in the exe with no deleter (thus with the default one), the dll will call the same deleter that would have been called from the exe if the last instance was deleted in the exe?

Yes, *but* that assumes binary compatibility.

Comment: just to be sure I got it right: if the `std::shared_ptr` was created in the exe with no deleter (thus with the default one), the dll will call the same deleter that would have been called from the exe if the last instance was deleted in the exe?

Comment: Yes, *but* that assumes binary compatibility.